# redirect_to throws forbidden AFTER including conditional clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, response.redirect

Strangest things I've seen yet.

In the controller, I try to redirect to send the user to another website:

```
redirect_to "http://google.com" --> This works.
```

BUT, if I do this:

```
if @model.true_boolean
  redirect_to "http://google.com" --> this now gives me a Completed 403 Forbidden
else
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

BUT this works:

```
if true
  redirect_to "http://google.com" --> this is ok now
else
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

If I'm getting to the redirect, obviously the boolean is true, but it's changing "something"...

How can adding an if statement change anything? I've looked at the request data and it all seems to match. I've spend hours here and elsewhere looking. Any takers on this frustrating encounter with the bowels of our dear ROR.

Comment: What is your model?  It seems that's your problem, since whenever you don't reference it, your redirect works fine.

Comment: My model is for registrations and the boolean is just a flag true or false. But the fact that it even goes to the redirect would tell me that it agrees that it's true and should render the redirect. There's magic happening somewhere. How can the redirect result be influenced by the model check it allowed through? it's like it's adding an artifact to the transaction somehow? Or it's something really dumb I've over looked.

Comment: While I can't say for sure (unless you have a publicly accessible page I can view where this is happening), I'm guessing that trying to access the model is triggering the 403, not the redirect command.  However, I'm not that familiar with Ruby on Rails, so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Ok. So it looks like my app is triggering twice everytime I click the button... and the redirect is being tripped onto itself causing the forbidden... does that make sense?

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, I've been caught by "turbo link". My bad. My apologies. Removing turbo link now. ROR4... why turbo link... why???

Comment: I had the same problem redirecting to an external website.
It was executing the action twice. Removing turbo link with 'no-turbolink' => true solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned. I removed Turbo Links from my ROR4 app, and it stopped tripping over it's own feet. Thanks Derek for leading me to look at the code differently.

Comment: You can disable turbolink only for current button. By adding to link data: {'no-turbolink' => true}

Answer (score 1):

Turbolinks is adding a 403 response status code behind the scene when you redirect a turbolink request to another domain.

I wrote a short [post](http://blog.guenterglueck.com/2015/05/29/turbolinks-and-the-403-redirect/) about that to give more insight. Hope it helps.